# Best practice to pass multiple QSqlRecord to another top level Widget?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtableview, qsqlquery

I have a `QTableView` bound with a `QSqlTableModel` (SQLite backend). I need to allow users to select as many as (if not all) records/rows from thousands of those and then pass the selection to dialog.

Right now, I have created a custom (holder) type, populate a QList of it and pass the pointer to **the** dialog like below:

```
#ifndef _ROW_HOLDER_H
#define _ROW_HOLDER_H


#include <QList>
#include <QString>
#include <QSqlRecord>

class RowHolder {

public:
    QString field1;
    QString field2;
    QString field3;
    explicit RowHolder(const QSqlRecord &record);
};

typedef QList<RowHolder> RowHolders;


#endif // _ROW_HOLDER_H
```

I pass it to the dialog like below:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("... valid SQL query ...");
auto list = new RowHolders();
while (query.next()) {
    list->append(RowHolder(query.record()));
}
TheDialog dialog(list, this);
dialog.exec();
delete list;
```

It is working fine, but I do not feel comfortable with it as it (seems to be) not efficient at all. Can this be improved? Is there any better way?

Comment: _but I do not feel comfortable with it as it (seems to be) not efficient_ .. unless you are specific with behavioral metric it won't be easy **even for you** to make conclusions

Comment: Perhaps you could pass the SQL query in a signal to the other mainwindow, then connect to the DB and execute the statement from your mainwindow?